# Unable to retrieve NTLM authenticated webpage with Python because of HTTP 302

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, ntlm, http-status-code-302

Can anyone help me with the python code that I have below? It is some open source that I've slightly modified for my own use. I am attempting to access a webpage from a Windows server that is running NTLM authentication. At first my problem was keeping a persistent connection so that I wouldn't get the http 401 error. Now I've gotten past that, but what happens is I get an http 302 redirect error along with a cookie sent back in the set-cookie of the response. Hence I added a cookie handler, but that has not done anything. Additionally the 'Location' field returned from the server, contains the original URL that I submitted in the first place. I don't understand this. Why would the location field sent back from the server for a redirect, have the same exact URL I submitted?!

```
import urllib2
import httplib, socket 
import cookielib
import ntlm 
from ntlm import ntlm 

class AbstractNtlmAuthHandler: 

   httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1 
   url1 = ""

   def __init__(self, password_mgr=None): 
      if password_mgr is None: 
         password_mgr = HTTPPasswordMgr() 
      self.passwd = password_mgr 
      self.add_password = self.passwd.add_password 

    def http_error_authentication_required(self, auth_header_field, req, fp, headers): 
      auth_header_value = headers.get(auth_header_field, None) 
      if auth_header_field: 
         if 'ntlm' in auth_header_value.lower(): 
         if auth_header_value is not None and 'ntlm' in auth_header_value.lower(): 
            fp.close() 
            return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(req, auth_header_field, None, headers) 

   def retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(self, req, auth_header_field, realm, headers): 

      print req.get_full_url()
      print "\n\n"

      #user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, req.get_full_url()) 
      user, pw = self.passwd.find_user_password(realm, url1) 
      if pw is not None: 
     # ntlm secures a socket, so we must use the same socket for the complete handshake 
     headers = dict(req.headers) 
     headers.update(req.unredirected_hdrs) 
     auth = 'NTLM %s' % ntlm.create_NTLM_NEGOTIATE_MESSAGE(user) 

     if req.headers.get(self.auth_header, None) == auth: 
        return None 
     headers[self.auth_header] = auth 

     host = req.get_host() 
     if not host: 
        raise URLError('no host given') 
     h = None 
     if req.get_full_url().startswith('https://'): 
        h = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host) # will parse host:port 
     else: 
        h = httplib.HTTPConnection(host) # will parse host:port 
         # we must keep the connection because NTLM authenticates the connection, not single requests 
         headers["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive" 
         headers = dict((name.title(), val) for name, val in headers.items()) 
         h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers) 
         r = h.getresponse() 
         r.begin() 
         r._safe_read(int(r.getheader('content-length'))) 
         if r.getheader('set-cookie'): 
            # this is important for some web applications that store authentication-related info in cookies (it took a long time to figure out) 
            headers['Cookie'] = r.getheader('set-cookie') 
         r.fp = None # remove the reference to the socket, so that it can not be closed by the response object (we want to keep the socket open) 
         auth_header_value = r.getheader(auth_header_field, None) 
         (ServerChallenge, NegotiateFlags) = ntlm.parse_NTLM_CHALLENGE_MESSAGE   (auth_header_value[5:]) 
         user_parts = user.split('\\', 1) 
         DomainName = user_parts[0].upper() 
         UserName = user_parts[1] 
         auth = 'NTLM %s' % ntlm.create_NTLM_AUTHENTICATE_MESSAGE(ServerChallenge, UserName, DomainName, pw, NegotiateFlags) 
         headers[self.auth_header] = auth 
         headers["Connection"] = "Close" 
         headers = dict((name.title(), val) for name, val in headers.items()) 
         try: 
            h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers) 
            # none of the configured handlers are triggered, for example redirect-responses are not handled! 
            return h.getresponse() 
         except socket.error, err: 
            raise URLError(err) 
      else: 
         return None 


class HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(AbstractNtlmAuthHandler, urllib2.BaseHandler): 

   auth_header = 'Authorization' 

   def http_error_401(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers): 
      return self.http_error_authentication_required('www-authenticate', req, fp, headers) 


class ProxyNtlmAuthHandler(AbstractNtlmAuthHandler, urllib2.BaseHandler): 
   auth_header = 'Proxy-authorization' 
   def http_error_407(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers): 
      return self.http_error_authentication_required('proxy-authenticate', req, fp, headers) 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
   url = 'HTTP WEB ADDRESS HERE'
   url1 = url

   user = 'USERNAME'
   password = 'PASSWORD' 
   user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
   data = ""
   headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }


   passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm() 
   passman.add_password(None, url, user, password) 


   cookie_jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
   cookie_handler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar)

   redirect = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()
   auth_basic = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman) 
   auth_digest = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(passman) 
   auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman) 

   opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_handler, auth_NTLM, auth_basic, auth_digest, redirect)
   urllib2.install_opener(opener) 

   req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: To answer the last part of your question: it's asking you to re-submit your request for the page, but this time *with* the cookie data (so it knows you're already authenticated and it can serve you up the content that you're authorized to see).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but shouldn't python's cookie handler take care of this for me? I'm assuming I have to manually re-submit then? :-/

Comment: I see that the code saves the cookie when it receives it in the server's response, which is good. I think that the next step is to follow the servers suggestion (the 301 code) to reload the page--but this time the cookie that you have stored is included in the request.

Comment: So I did what you suggsted. I sent back both an SMIDENTITY and an SMSESSION cookie in the header request back to the server for the web page. This time, it responded with another 302 error along with 2 new cookies. ?!?! What the heck?

Answer (score 5):

once you get the response from the server, check if it is a 302 status. If it is a 302 status get the coookies and make another request with the cookie information

```
if(response.code==302):
        header={'Cookie':response.headers['Set-Cookie']}
        req=urllib2.Request(thesameurl,None,header)
        response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
response.read()
```